# Is Mono for OSX viable for learning C#?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I need to learn C#. All of my computers are Macs running the latest version of OS X. I do not **want** to use Windows, but I will if I must.

That being said, as a new programmer, can I learn C# efficiently with this Mono platform on OS X?

**Edit** I'm looking to learn C# to gain programming knowledge and start indie game development. After a reasonable understanding is achieved I will then look at some gaming frameworks/platforms and or a more OS specific language.

Comment: It's certainly possible to learn C# w/ Mono on OS X, but what are you going to be using it for? The vast majority of C# jobs are for doing Windows programming, although there are some other environments like Unity that use C#+Mono.

Comment: @adam vandenberg edited my question.

Comment: Have you considered Qt? IMO it's a better cross-platform development environment. I shopped around for a long time (Python, Java, Mono, etc...) but Qt provides a great experience across platforms, is easy enough to learn (it's C++), and has excellent documentation. I'd encourage you to check it out. I am using it to move my current C# application over to Mac and Linux. It's been a great learning experience. http://qt.nokia.com

Answer (score 3):

In a word: Yes.

First of all, thanks Jonathan Pobst for updating [What Is Mono](http://mono-project.com/What_is_Mono) page. With that said, Mono supports all versions of C# at present, that is 1.0 to 4.0.

Since your plan is to ***learn the language first*** before looking into other things, such as frameworks and tools, you should be fine with Mono. Once you start getting into platform-specific development (i.e., Windows GUI), then you might want to consider switching over to a Windows machine.

http://mono-project.com/What_is_Mono
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions

Comment: Updated the "What Is Mono" page to reflect that Mono now supports all versions of C#, including 4.0.

Comment: Good stuff! It's awesome to see developers like you active in the community. I'll update my post. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be developing for Windows, then using a Windows machine is your best bet.  If you are simply trying to learn the language, Mono should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, but just keep in mind that while most of the example code will work, some may not on the Mono framework as the implementation is not 100% compatible with .NET Framework.  Also, of course some things like WPF aren't be supported by Mono.

I have used Monodevelop on Linux and it mostly works but because I also develop on Windows with VS2010, I am put off by using the inferior Monodevelop but as a newbie it shouldn't matter to you much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should be fine seeing as MonoMac has come out. http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac

If your wanting to use it for games with OpenGL, download this repo and look at the openGL stuff to get started. Then go to places like NeHe to learn more about GL ect..

You will need to download & install git to pull the repo:: http://git-scm.com/download

MonoMac Samples:: https://github.com/mono/monomac/tree/master/samples/

NeHe:: http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Code Sampler:: http://www.codesampler.com/

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

To just learn the C# language and CLR core libraries which are not graphics related, C# / MonoDevelop is okay.

To learn graphics programming, game programming for OS X, I suggest you first learn Objective-C, Cocoa and then MonoDevelop/MonoMac. The reason is that the Cocoa API's are designed around the Objective-C language which has fundamental differences to C#. Using Cocoa via C# is easy to begin with, but quickly makes little sense unless you understand Cocoa patterns & Objective-C.